# Need to grab users listed inside wheel_user_array. Everything inside of the [] using python re (regex) module

Tags: python, arrays, regex, python-3.x, list

I have a block of code in a big puppet file ".pp" I want to grab just the user names inside of a block. Here is what the block looks like:

```
 $wheel_user_array = [
    'user1',
    'user2',
    'user3',
    'user4',
    'user5',
    'user6'
  ]
```

I need to grab whatever is in between the [] inside of wheel_user_array. I want to do so with the re module. This array can vary in size depending on the users so I need to be able to grab everything inside of this array.

The users in the array change as users are added to it and removed. So in order to grab all new users I wanted to grab everything in between the [] markers in the wheel_user_array. I wanted to be able to store the output in a list. The file has other contents before and after this section of code, but I'm only interested in grabbing the users in the wheel_user_array.

Comment: Is there no other way around this? What is actually the issue, by the way?

Comment: @AMC I could always use the subproccess module along with grep to grab the users, but I wanted to use re instead of relying on Linux commands. The issue is I have a script that looks for local users in this array to determine if they exist on my systems. If their names are in the array they exist if not then I know they don't exist. So each time my script runs it goes and grabs the users in this array and stores them as a list. Then I was going to see if the username existed in the list. If it does then I would know the user is still active.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what the problem is, sorry...

Comment: In your description you should likely make more clear that you want to find these in a large file itself and post some of the text around the array in your code block so everyone knows it's a file and not an actual script. I assume people "-1'ed" you because they presumed you could just use indeces.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the confusion everyone. I was able to resolve the question. I had a large .pp file which I could not post, but the wheel user array was the block of code I needed to capture out of the large file. I used the following regex command to grab what I needed:

## Load puppet file

```
with open(puppet_file, 'r') as f:
    search_strings = f.read()
```

## Grab the pattern I needed:

```
    pattern = re.compile(r'\s{2}(\$wheel.*\[|])[\s\S]*?(?=\n.*?=|$)')
    matches = pattern.finditer(search_strings)
```

## Cleaned up matches to only store the usernames in a list:

```
for match in matches:
    reg_string = match.group(0)
s = reg_string.splitlines()

pe_users = []
for x in s[1:-1]:
    pe_users.append(x.replace(' ','').replace(',',''))
```

This left me with the pe_users list which only contained the users inside the initial wheel array I needed to store.

A lot of credit goes to Corey's youtube channel [Python re Module](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8L6KVGG-7o)